# Inverse of block anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be an invertible block anti-diagonal matrix (with $d$ blocks), i.e.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} & & & A_1 \\ & & A_2 & \\ & \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot}} &  & \\ A_d\end{pmatrix},
$$
with all square blocks $A_1, \ldots, A_d$ invertible. Is there a formula for its inverse?

In the diagonal case, it is just the diagonal block matrix with the inverses of the blocks, is there an equivalent for the anti-diagonal case?

Comment: Are the blocks $A_i$ the same size matrix or potentially different sizes?

Comment: @snulty In my specific case, yes. It would be interesting though to have generic square blocks.

Comment: Can you do the case where the blocks are $1\times 1$? That gives a pretty clear hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the answer with all the blocks invertible.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} & & & A_1 \\ & & A_2 & \\ & \dots &  & \\ A_d\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} & & & A_d^{-1} \\ & & A_{d-1}^{-1} & \\ & \dots &  & \\ A_1^{-1}\end{pmatrix},
$$
we have

$$AB=I$$

Comment: very neat answer +1

Answer (score 5):

There exists a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $\rm P$ such that

$${\rm A P} = \mbox{diag} \left( {\rm A}_1, {\rm A}_2, \dots, {\rm A}_d \right)$$

Assuming that all the ${\rm A}_i$ blocks are invertible,

$$\left( \rm A P \right)^{-1} = {\rm P}^\top {\rm A}^{-1} = \mbox{diag} \left( {\rm A}_1^{-1}, {\rm A}_2^{-1}, \dots, {\rm A}_d^{-1} \right)$$

and, thus,

$${\rm A}^{-1} = \color{blue}{{\rm P} \, \mbox{diag} \left( {\rm A}_1^{-1}, {\rm A}_2^{-1}, \dots, {\rm A}_d^{-1} \right)}$$

For example, if $d = 3$,

$${\rm A}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} & & {\rm I}\\ & {\rm I} & \\ {\rm I} & & \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} {\rm A}_1^{-1} & & \\ & {\rm A}_2^{-1} & \\ & & {\rm A}_3^{-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} & & {\rm A}_3^{-1}\\ & {\rm A}_2^{-1} & \\ {\rm A}_1^{-1} & & \end{bmatrix}$$

---

[linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [block-matrices](/questions/tagged/block-matrices) [permutation-matrices](/questions/tagged/permutation-matrices)

Comment: SW-NE dots using `\cdot^{\textstyle \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot}}`: $$\begin{bmatrix} & & {\rm I}\\ & \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot}}  & \\ {\rm I} & & \end{bmatrix}$$